# Angular JS custom directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Say I have a service that returns me an HTML like

```
Welcome {{UserName}}
```

now even when UserName is defined in current scope, that angular expression doesn't get decoded means for me the result should be like 
Welcome Dummy User but the achieved result is like Welcome {{UserName}}

Comment: I think you are going to have to supply more context to the question.  Maybe some more illustrative HTML and JavaScript?  Ideally, a small jsFiddle.

Comment: Would also like to mention that I have tried $compile in both ways i.e. $compile(containerElem, $scope) and $compile(containerElem)($scope) and that doesn't work as well

Comment: @Kolban here you have a sample code
[link]http://plnkr.co/edit/B1BsXozy12bHJqgvbUaC?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cw5TnM0MdLnAwViXOD2B?p=preview).

Here is the line of code which is going to do the magic (compile a string with markup into an interpolation function and then execute is against the scope.)

```
$element.parent().append($interpolate(dummyService.htmlStr)($scope));
```